# building a query from a parent attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Getting the following error from a query I'm trying to make
"missing FROM-clause entry"

Basically, I have questions that have many answers and I'm trying to get all the answers that belong to a question with 'x' category

```
Answer.joins(:question).
from('answers').
where(:question => {:category => @category}).
sort_by(&:created_at).
reverse.
paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

Comment: Do you really need from()?  What query do you get if you remove from?

Comment: I get the same without the from, ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in AnswersController#category

PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "question"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Answer.joins(:question => :category).where...
```

How about:

```
Answer.joins(question: category).where("categories.name = ?", @category).order("answers.created at ASC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

Comment: nope, didn't work, here's what I got.....Answer.joins(:question => :category).where(:question => {:category => @category}).sort_by(&:created_at).reverse.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)

Comment: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "question"

Comment: thanks for the help, getting somewhere at least now...error now says stack level too deep

Comment: Add your models code to the question. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446055/stack-level-too-deep-error - `stack level too deep` means you have an infinite recursive call somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, not finding the recursive call. My question model does belong_to a category model, could that cause an issue