# stack level too deep on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason I'm getting stack level too deep on my group#create, and I can't recall making any changes before it started showing this error.

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController

 def new
  @group = current_user.company.groups.new
 end

 def create
    @group = current_user.company.groups.new(group_params)
    if @group.save
      flash[:success] = 'saved'
      redirect_to groups_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def group_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:name, user_ids: [])
  end
end



class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
  # questions
  has_many :question_participants, as: :questionable
  has_many :questions, through: :question_participants

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_memberships

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

and group_memberships:

```
class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :group_id }
end
```

and user:

```
# User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  # groups
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :group_questions, through: :groups, source: :questions
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships
```

form:

```
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true %>

    <%= f.label :user_ids %>
    <%= f.collection_select :user_ids, User.order(:first_name), :id, :first_name, {},
      { multiple: true } %>


  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

it happens when I submit, irrelevant if there's any data there or not.

```
Started POST "/groups" for ::1 at 2015-10-23 09:37:08 +0200
Processing by GroupsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5OCDQ27Aepg4ptjJdj9TF5kZkNcqE2GjnEh3OqH6gftOKLp+uIeLI3KDycImSM4WvUIRELghyVdqhURy7tLsWg==", "group"=>{"name"=>"", "user_ids"=>[""]}, "commit"=>"create"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)

SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
  newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:89:in `'
```

my controller:

Comment: Can you share more of the stack trace? Are there any callbacks in your models?

Comment: that's it, honestly. I've updated with the POST info however. I haven't removed any info from my group model.

Comment: has_many :users is not necessarily the cause. when you comment it out the code breaks before it starts the recursion

Comment: I suspect this might have something to do with accepts_nested_attributes_for , can you post the code of group_memeberships?

Comment: I still don't see what's the issue, but maybe this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446055/stack-level-too-deep-error-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, after almost 9 hours straight working on debugging this. I'll try to write this detailed so people in a similar situation can fix this asap, because this is one hell of a bug to fix.

The issue was a problem with my bullet gem. If you have 'gem bullet' to look for N+1 then removing it and the initializer worked for me.

However if you don't have this / or if you do and you want to see how I figured out that it was the problem what I did was:

1. Create a new file called trace.rb in your config/initializer/
2. Insert this code into it:

-

```
$enable_tracing = false
#$trace_out = File.open(Rails.root + 'trace.txt', 'w')

set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  if $enable_tracing && event == 'call'
    #$trace_out.puts "#{file}:#{line} #{classname}##{id}"
    raise "crash me" if caller_locations.length > 500
  end
}

$enable_tracing = true
```

now re-run (and remember to restart your rails server because it's an initializer file) the place where you get the issue, and it will loop over the problem. In my case I got this:

```
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
  bullet (4.14.9) lib/bullet/active_record42.rb:194:in `has_cached_counter?'
```

and for there I was able to use reason and understand that the problem was with bullet. However as seen in my question I had absolutely no error message displaying and no way of telling that this was the issue.

Hope this works for future people!

Comment: I get - config/initializers/trace.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `caller_locations' for main:Object (NameError) - so when you restart your server, do you pass in some argument or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Please modify the model like:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships
  has_many :group_memberships
end
```

group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  has_many :group_memberships
  # questions
  has_many :question_participants, as: :questionable
  has_many :questions, through: :question_participants

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_memberships

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

group_membership.rb

```
class GroupMemberhip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: so it seems like the problem is   has_many :users, through: :group_memberships however, the association is true in the sense that a a group has many users through group membership?

Answer (score 1):

`stack level too deep` basically means **infinite loop**

---

You've got an infinitely recursive loop in your `groups#create` method somewhere; I'd surmise - like the others - that it's do with `current_user.company.groups`...

```
#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :groups
end

#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

#app/models/membership.rb
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I think the problem is that you're calling `groups` on a `company` belonging to a particular `user`, which Rails will automatically assume to have a `user` attribute too. IE it will call `find groups where id = [company_id] and user_id = [user_id]`

If you want to create a group on a company, you *don't* have to use `current_user` (I think this is what's causing the problem):

```
def create
    company = Company.find_by id: current_user.id
    @group  = company.groups.new group_params
    if @group.save
      flash[:success] = 'saved'
      redirect_to groups_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

This is not correct (it will be best to call `current_user.company`), but it will remove the `user` element from your call.

I think that because you're allowing the addition of users to groups, *and* calling `current_user`, Rails is getting might confused.

If you try the above code it should work

---

Anyway, it's bad practice ([law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)) to have many different "connections" on a single object. It translates simply into *you shouldn't have more than one "dot" in your calls*:

```
current_user.groups
```

You generally get around this by using [`alias_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute), but that's another story :)

---

## Update

Some observations after looking at your repo:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :company
   has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :company
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
    has_many :groups #-> group.users.each
end
```

-

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :company

    private

    def company
       current_user.company
    end
end

#app/controllers/groups_controller.rb
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @groups = company.groups.all
   end

   def new
      @users = User.where.not(id: current_user.id).order(:first_name)
      @group = company.groups.new
   end

   def create
      @group = company.groups.new group_params
      @group.save
   end
end
```

This should allow you to populate the `group` with users as follows:

```
#app/views/groups/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.collection_select :user_ids, @users, :id, :first_name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for the input - I tried doing what you suggested, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Errors / console log.

Comment: same thing,
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Company Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)

SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:89:in `'

Comment: Why is the user record being called twice? This is highly suspicious to me

Comment: What did you say fixed the issue last time? Removing the `has_many :through`?

Comment: One note on the setup you have, company does not belong to a user, it has many users.  If I remove has_many :users, through: :group_memberships then I get unknown attribute user_ids for Group.

Comment: This is crazy - do you have a repo I could look at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93140/discussion-between-sebastian-jennings-almnes-and-rich-peck).

Answer (score 0):

The problem coming from the `many-to-many polymorphic relationship` with `questions` and you should indicate that the `group has_many users` as shown below:

Update the `group.rb` as the following:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
  # questions
  has_many :question_participants, as: :questionable
  has_many :questions, through: :question_participants, as: :questionable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_memberships

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

Comment: still getting stack level too deep :/