# Rspec and FactoryGirl: SystemStackError: stack level too deep rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have one spec and one factory and I am getting this error:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:9:in `relation_delegate_class'
```

When I try to use the verbage 'build' it works; but I need it to save to test data and 'create' doesn't work in `let!(:user) { create(:user) }` as it sets off that error. Rspec seems to work fine.

I am running ruby 2.2.2; using rspec, and factory girl

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe API::V1::CurrentUserController do
   let!(:user) { create(:user) }
    setup_api_authorization

   describe "GET 'show'" do
    before (:each) do
    setup_api_headers
    get 'show', subdomain: 'api', id: 'me'
   end
end


FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:participant] do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com" }
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    password 'testpass'
    password_confirmation { |user| user.password }
    role_id {4}
 end
end
```

Comment: Please show your `User` model. Do you have any callbacks, such as `after_create`, `after_commit`, etc. in it?

Comment: The spec user model or the app one

Comment: Model from `app/models`.

Comment: Ok so I do have 3 after_create, 3 before_create and 1 after_save. I cannot post the whole model here what do these callbacks do to cause issues with rspec/factorygirl?

Comment: If you call `#update` or `#save` in your callbacks it might lead to this error.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this or a better framework to use?

Comment: You shouldn't do that if that's what you're doing. You can post your callbacks here to get better feedback.

Comment: I don't get though how do these callbacks cause issue with factory girl. I need a better understanding to figure out how to fix this. I am basically calling methods and workers to run and do extra logic in other databases when a user is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup associations you can just call the name of the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:participant] do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com" }
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    password 'testpass'
    password_confirmation { password  }
    role
  end
end
```

Never hardcode IDs into your factories - you're only setting yourself up for a world of hurt.

If you are using Rolify you can use a callback to add a role to a user instead:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, aliases: [:participant] do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.com" }
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    password 'testpass'
    password_confirmation { password }
    after(:create) { |user| user.add_role(:peasant) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> This error generally happens when you accidentally recursively
>   changing an attribute. If you have a username attribute in User model,
>   and a virtual attribute named username, that is directly changing the
>   username, you end up calling the virtual, the virtual calls the
>   virtual again and so on.. Therefore, take a look on whether something
>   like that happens somewhere in your code.

[Stack level too deep error in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446055/stack-level-too-deep-error-in-ruby-on-rails)